# Google Chrome - "click to play" functionality per plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

I am using Google Chrome's "click to play" functionality to prevent Flash plugins from running unless I choose to.  This is fantastic and at last my machine is fast again.

Problem is I love the Google Chrome built in PDF viewer and I don't want to click to have PDF's displayed.

Anyone know if it is possible to configure "click to play" only for Adobe Flash?